# In kendo UI how to draw vertical line in a line chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-chart

[image]How to draw a vertical line in a line chart using Html5 and kendo UI ? can anyone help me out to solve this problem ?

Comment: vertical or horizontal line? I think, there is a way to define horizontal line in `kendoui`.

Comment: Vertical line only. I am newbie to kendo ui hence can you explain briefly ?

Comment: I think, its not possible to draw vertical line in `kendoui`(in middle of charts), but as i said horizontal line can be drawn with `plotbands`. Can you tell me why you need a vertical line, with example.

Comment: If i have a line chart with vertical columns as 10,20,30,..... and horizontal column with months say jan to dec and after that again jan to dec for separation i need a vertical line with some color.

Comment: i have added the sample image just like that i want @Mohit Pandey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// let chart be the id
$("#chart").kendoChart({
     categoryAxis: {
         notes: {
             line: {
                 length: 300
             },
             data: [{
                 value: new Date(2012, 0, 3),
                 label: {
                     text: "-" //text you want to show
                 } 
             }]
         }
     }
 });
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/obuweca/26

/*** WITHOUT CIRCLE ***/

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    categoryAxis: {
        notes: {
            line: {
                length: 300
            },
            icon: {
                border: {
                    width: 0
                }
            },
            // Initial notes
            data: [{
                value: new Date(2012, 0, 3)
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/obuweca/29/

Comment: as you mentioned this works fine thanks :) but on top of the vertical line a circle is placed right ? whatever text we put there will be displayed. But i don't want to display the circle instead just vertical line is enough for me ??? can you help out that ?

Comment: @arun: please look at the edited code. If it resolve your issue, you can up-vote it as well.

Comment: @ Mohit Pandey thanks for your reply :) and in mean time i had found other solution too place visible as false for the label that too worked out. And your answer also worked :)

Answer (score 1):

In kendo documentation is example how do draw custom lines on chart. Horizontal and vertical.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/custom-plot-bands

You can customize lines by editing stroke:

```
 stroke: {
          color: "red",
          width: 1,
          dashType:"dash"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use the column-Chart.

Just extend the series:

```
  series: [{
                type: "line",
                field: "value",
                categoryField: "date"
            },
            {
                type:"column", 
                field: "valueColumn", 
                gap: 300
            }]
```

and the dataSource.data with a new field like: valueColumn.

See also the [Example](http://jsbin.com/buqeroyeqi/7/edit?html,output).